# When should floated HTML elements be cleared exactly?

Tags: html, css

Could anyone explain when should the floated elements get cleared?

I have noticed sometimes when I make something in HTML, and I don't clear them, it still all looks good!

Also can `overflow:hidden` be used as a replacement for clearing?

Look at this example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .a { background-color: red; overflow: hidden }
    .floated-left { float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>div with class a, that does have overflow:hidden:</p>
  <div class="a">
    <div class="floated-left">Hi,</div>
    <div class="floated-left">Mom!</div>
  </div>

  <p>i didn't clear anything</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I didn't clear the floated divs, but set `overflow:hidden` for the `.a` class and the `<p>` below appeared in normal element flow.

However, if I removed `overflow:hidden` from the `.a` class, `<p>` gets displaced.

Please explain!

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For block-level, non-replaced elements, when `overflow` isn't set to "visible" and `height` isn't "auto", the [element's height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height) depends on its descendents ([CSS 2.1 § 10.6.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#block-root-margin)). Thus when you set `overflow: hidden` on `.a`, it stretches to contain the floated descendents. The `<p>` is below `.a`, so it's below the floats.

Without `overflow: hidden`, `.a` doesn't contain the floated children; its calculated height is 0. The `<p>` is still below `.a`, but not the floats. The floats push the inline content of `<p>`, as floats are wont to do.

Try putting borders around `.a` and paragraphs to more clearly see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

`overflow: hidden` should be used as a replacement for clearing divs whenever it can be, which is most of the time.

Comment: Note we can also distinguish between stretching parents of floats and clearing.

Comment: Also see http://blue-anvil.com/archives/experiments-with-floats-whats-the-best-method-of-clearance/

Answer (score 2):

IF you need to float the elements around an tire block as unit and the containing element needs to expand vertically to the height of whichever is highest. Otherwise the text/inline elements of the non-floated adjacent elements will flow around the float. If this content ends up being taller than your float then youll be ok... the container will expand. If however the floated elemnt is taller, then youll need to clear it if you want the container to be as tall as the float.

Answer (score 1):

Just as I replied in your other post [When should overflow:hidden be used for a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166074/when-should-overflowhidden-be-used-for-a-div/2166121#2166121) this is because the child elements of the a div throw the margins out of bound for a when overflow is anything other than visible. When overflow is visible, a technically stops at the boundary of the div for "Mom!". When it is other than visible (overflow, scroll, auto), the boundary continues until it reaches the boundary of its own parent (in this case the right edge of the browser). The new block element may not begin until it has space to go in. Effective when overflow is visible, it may begin directly after the margin boundary of the last floated div. When it is other, it must wait for a full break in the div.